# YOLOv8 Улучшение собственной обученной модели

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект

Интересует то как можно улучшить свою обученную модель. Я обучил модель для распознавания 1 объекта провел 300 эпох, batch=16 на медиум модели yolo. Но она не совершенна все еще не до конца распознает объекты особенно когда они находятся далеко либо в тени. Вот и хочу дообучить ее на дополнительных изображения если конечно это возможно. Просто не хочется заново обучать модель с нуля так как занимает это очень много времени.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, больше деталей.  Может показать картинки, на которых возникают проблемы.  И какой процент успеха сейчас.